# Excel function to remove parameters from URL

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a cell in Excel filled with URL link, that goes

`https://something.com/team?WT_from=TopMenu&WT_fname1=team`

And I need to remove all parameters `?WT_from=TopMenu&WT_fname1=team` so that the cell will look like this: `https://something.com/team`

Although all cells differs, hence there are no two same parameters. That means, i need a general formula removing all content behind the first quistionmark.

I tried to experiment with TRIM function, but none work. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you let us know what exactly defines "all parameters". Do you mean you want to trim the text from the 1st "?" onwards? Also, no matter how poor, including your own attempt does help. Please edit it into your question.

Comment: As per you edit: `=LEFT(A1,FIND("?",A1&"?")-1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the text element at the end of the string is always the same, you can use the Find and Replace functions in excel. If your URL is in cell A1 the following should work

```
=REPLACE(A1,FIND("?WT_from=TopMenu&WT_fname1=team",A1),LEN(A1),"")
```

The find formula `(FIND("?WT_from=TopMenu&WT_fname1=team",A1))`, finds the relevent text in cell A1 and outputs a value that denotes at what character the string starts

The replace formula then looks in cell A1, finds where the text value starts and then uses the LEN function to find the total length of the text and then replaces this with blank. (The "" at the end of the formula)

This wont work if the text variable at the end is different each time or if there is other text at the end of the element that you want to remove, that you dont want to remove.

As per your edit, to remove all text after a ? you would need the following formula

```
=REPLACE(A1,FIND("?",A1),LEN(A1),"")
```

Comment: Thanks! How about the parametry differs and I would like to always trim all the text behind the first “?”

Comment: you would just need to replace the full parameter value in the above formula to be a ? so - =REPLACE(A1,FIND("?",A1),LEN(A1),"")